# Установленное разрешение камеры автоматически меняется при получении видеопотока для PIKVM

Tags: linux, камера, raspberry-pi, kvm

Всем привет, и заранее спасибо за помощь

Описываю задачу в целом: Есть bli-kvm, на которую установлен PIKVM. Видеопоток с платформы подключен в hdmi разъем bli-kvm (предназначен для камеры) и транслируется на PIKVM. Стандартное разрешение видеопотока: 800х600, а нужно поменять его на 1024х768.

Для этого пользовался командой v4l2-ctl. Проблема заключается в том, что я могу поменять разрешение командой `v4l2-ctl --set-dv-bt-timings width=1024,height=786`,
оно поменяется, что я проверяю командой `v4l2-ctl --get-dv-timings`, но после того как я включаю сервис PIKVM командой `systemctl start kvmd` (и, соответственно, начинаю получать видеопоток), разрешение, которое я изменил, сбрасывается обратно.

Прошу объяснить, почему так происходит, по возможности, и как сделать так, чтобы разрешение менялось и больше не сбрасывалось

Ниже вывод терминала, где наглядно показано изменение разрешения после старта сервиса
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]